# How do I exit from input after using a `:i` command?

Tags: user-input

I got stuck in ex input mode by typing `:i`. Now I cannot use any commands. All there is just a string of text. Pressing escape does not get me out of it, typing `:visual` does not get me out of it, and typing `visual` does not get me out of it. How do I get out of it?

Comment: Enter a line containing a simple dot `.` or hit `C-c`.

Comment: Have you tried `ctrl-c`? Edit: user9444929 was a second faster :-)

Answer (score 24):

`:insert` will keep asking for lines until you type a line only containing `.`. For more help see `:h :i`.

Comment: `ctrl-c`did not work for me. Try to type `quit!` to exit. Then, vi the file again.

Comment: **:insert** and **.** Those two lines above helped me to quit that Ex mode. After pressing **Enter**, it went back to the normal mode where I am able to use ''**:**''. From that mode I just closed and launched again. Thank you Peter Rincker

Answer (score 0):

To leave the input mode and get back to terminal press esc :qa!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Unfortunately the answer you’ve posted doesn’t answer the asked question, but thanks for spreading the knowledge!